# How do I find the flux through a square?

Tags: gauss-law

Suppose there is a charge of $2\mu C$ 20cm above the center of a square of side length 40cm and one wishes to find the flux through that square.  The book I am reading claims that the answer to this problem is $1.13 \mbox{x} 10^5 \frac{Nm^2}{C}$

How can this possibly be correct?

Gauss Law states $$\Phi_E = \frac{Qenc}{\epsilon_0}$$

Suppose I then let the Gaussian surface be a cube of side length 40cm centered around and enclosing the charge.  The total flux through all six faces should be given by the above equation, so a sixth of that should yield the flux through one square, no?  Doing this yields $$\frac{1}{6}\frac{2*10^{-6}C}{8.854*10^{-12}\frac{C^2}{Nm^2}} = 3.76 * 10^4\frac{Nm^2}{C}$$

Either I don't know how to use a calculator, I don't understand Gauss' Law, or the textbook has a terrible typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is absolutely fine, all sides of the cube are equivalent to one another, and your calculation is correct.

Since their answer is as though there was 3 times as much charge, my guess is they have made a typo when they did the calculation.

Comment: I figured it had to be a typo, and until someone says differently I'll give you best answer for sanity checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the charge being 6 times the charge through a cube is wrong.  There is no flux through planes parallel to the direction of the field, so the flux through the cube is only 2 times the amount through the specified surface.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer. The charge is placed at the center, and the field is radial. There is no surface parallel to the field.